# C# RegEx Keep Line Breaks

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove all special characters except line breaks. Does anyone know of a RegEx that would accomplish this task? Here is my RegEx:

```
        string b = "ABC\r\nVVV";
        string a = Regex.Replace(b, "[^\\x20-\\x7E]", "");
```

Comment: Just add them to the negated character class, `"[^\\x20-\\x7E\r\n]+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You match any char other than a char from space to tilde with `"[^\\x20-\\x7E]"`. So, it matches CR and LF symbols. To avoid matching those chars, add them to the character class, and it is best to add `+` after the `]` to match 1 or more occurrences to remove whole sequences at once:

```
string a = Regex.Replace(b, "[^\\x20-\\x7E\r\n]+", "");
```

See the [regex demo at RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5Cx20-%5Cx7E%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B&i=Some%20%7E%0D%0AMore%C5%82%C4%85&r=).